# Exemplo de markdown não "escapado"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

Na página ["remover restrições de usuário novo [sic]"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user), o exemplo de markdown não está "escapado", aparecendo como um link comum:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(A propósito, seria melhor usar a expressão "novo usuário" - new user - em vez de "usuário novo" - young user).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. (nice freehand circles)